# mysql pivot table or something

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, pivot-table

Ok, I'm still a beginner in sql and can not figure this one out yet.
I have four tables: companies, persons, details, person_details.

```
companies: 
id, compname
(1, ACME), 
(2, ACME Group), ...

persons: 
id, name, lastname, company id
(1, donald, duck, 1), 
(2, lucky, luke, 1), 
(3, mickey, mouse, 2)

details: 
id, description
(1, 'weight'), 
(2, 'height'), 
(3, 'haircolor'), ...

person_details: 
id, persons id, details id, value
(1, 1, 1, 70), 
(2, 1, 3, 'red'), 
(3, 2, 1, 90), 
(4, 3, 2, 180)
```

As you can see, not all persons have all the details and the list of available details is variable.

Now, for a given arary of person ids and detail ids, I would like to get rows containing: company name and id, person name and last name, detail name and value for each of the details in the supplied array.
Let's say persons(1,2), details(1,3) should result in:

```
companies.id, companies.name, name, lastname, details.description, person_details.value,...    
    1, ACME, donald, duck, 'weight', 70, 'haircolor', 'red'
    2, ACEM, lucky, luke, 'weight', 90, 'haircolor', null
```

Help, please...

Comment: Update your output data with proper column name of above tables. And also update what have you tried?

Comment: I updated the output data. Tried all sorts of things, but, being a beginner, don't know if any of it made sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description it seems like you want to *pivot* the data but unfortunately MySQL does not have a *pivot* function so you will need to replicate it using an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement.

If you know the description values ahead of time you can hard-code your query to the following:

```
select c.id,
  c.compname,
  p.name,
  p.lastname,
  max(case when d.description = 'weight' then pd.value end) weight,
  max(case when d.description = 'haircolor' then pd.value end) haircolor,
  max(case when d.description = 'height' then pd.value end) height
from companies c
left join persons p
  on c.id = p.`company id`
left join person_details pd
  on p.id = pd.`persons id`
left join details d
  on pd.`details id` = d.id
-- where p.id in (1, 2)
group by c.id, c.compname, p.name, p.lastname
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5949d/8)

If you have an unknown number of values, then you can use a [prepared statement to generate this dynamically](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html) similar to this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN d.description = ''',
      description,
      ''' then pd.value end) AS ',
      description
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM details;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT c.id,
                      c.compname,
                      p.name,
                      p.lastname, ', @sql, ' 
                  from companies c
                  left join persons p
                    on c.id = p.`company id`
                  left join person_details pd
                    on p.id = pd.`persons id`
                  left join details d
                    on pd.`details id` = d.id
                  -- where p.id in (1, 2)
                  group by c.id, c.compname, p.name, p.lastname');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5949d/10)

Both versions generate the result:

```
| ID |   COMPNAME |   NAME | LASTNAME | WEIGHT | HEIGHT | HAIRCOLOR |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |       ACME | donald |     duck |     70 | (null) |       red |
|  1 |       ACME |  lucky |     luke |     90 | (null) |    (null) |
|  2 | ACME Group | mickey |    mouse | (null) |    180 |    (null) |
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I need. You only forgot to add 'where id in (1,3)' after 'from details'. Scratched my head a bit to fully understand what was going on but I've figured it out. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1768401 I had just commented it out so you could see the entire solution. :)